# Command line svn - "Version mismatch" error

Tags: svn, command-line

When entering `svn` in the command line I get the response:

```
$ svn
svn: E200019: Version mismatch in 'svn_diff' (expecting equality): found 1.9.6, expected 1.9.4
svn: E200019: Version mismatch in 'svn_delta' (expecting equality): found 1.9.6, expected 1.9.4
svn: E200019: Version mismatch in 'svn_ra' (expecting equality): found 1.9.6, expected 1.9.4
svn: E200019: Version mismatch in 'svn_wc' (expecting equality): found 1.9.6, expected 1.9.4
svn: E200019: Version mismatch in 'svn_client' (expecting equality): found 1.9.6, expected 1.9.4
svn: E200019: Version mismatch in 'svn_subr' (expecting equality): found 1.9.6, expected 1.9.4
```

I have the latest version of TortoiseSVN installed and have performed a full reboot of the computer.

I'm assuming the error is to do with an older version of subversion still being installed on the computer, however I assumed this would have been removed when I installed the latest version of Tortoise.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to use something like [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) when running `svn` to see which files or registry entries it's looking at when it throws those errors.

Comment: @cokeman19 Excellent advice, helped solved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue was that  `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe` was still version 1.9.4.

Modified TortoiseSVN within Programs and Features and this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is an issue with CollabNet Subversion Client setup with existing/in-use files. I was having this very same issue.

Cheking DLLs at installation directory I found there weren't upgraded.

To fix it I had to stop my svnserve manually, uninstall the client and install it again.

Comment: I don't have CollabNet Subversion Client installed unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Version mismatch in 'svn_fs_util' (expecting equality): found 1.9.7, expectedVersion mismatch in 'svn_fs_util' (expecting equality): found 1.9.7

Restart of svnserve (systemctl stop~start svnserve) solved the problem